# Displaying tooltip dynamically

Tags: vue.js

I need to display tooltip dynamically. I got an error while writing the v-for loop inside the span tag.

```
    <span v-if="documentType === 'CourierReciept' && documentGroup === 'CourierDocuments'">
      <label>{{UploadText}} {{f.DisplayName}}</label>
      <span v-if="f.IsRequired == true">*</span>
      <span v-tooltip=" <span v-for= "(s,index) in staticText" :key="index"> 
             {{staticText.name}}>"<i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
   </span>
```

Comment: I could solve it but your example is broken

Comment: <span v-if="documentType === 'CourierReciept' && documentGroup === 'CourierDocuments'"><label>{{UploadText}} {{f.DisplayName}}</label><span v-if="f.IsRequired == true">*</span><span v-tooltip=" <span v-for= "(s,index) in staticText" :key="index">{{staticText.name}}>"<i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>

Comment: i attached my code now can you help me

Answer (score 0):

The v-tooltip [docs](https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip#directive) give a pretty clear idea of using it dynamically. I'm going to assume you've correctly installed v-tooltip and it is ready to go. If you try

```
<span v-if="documentType === 'CourierReciept' && documentGroup === 'CourierDocuments'">
      <label>{{UploadText}} {{f.DisplayName}}</label>
      <span v-if="f.IsRequired == true">*</span>
      <span v-for= "(s,index) in staticText" :key="index">
        <span v-tooltip="s.name">
          <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </span>
</span>
```

Which is a lot of spans and will give you a heap of circles but may just work. If this isn't what you want I'd suggest setting up a jsfiddle or codepen or something that we could have a look at.

Comment: Thanks Andrew1325 . i got tooltip data dynamically but icon also repeating.i dont want want repeat the icon.can you slove this?

Comment: If you don't want the icon to repeat you need to take it out of the v-for loop. But if you do that you won't have anything for the tooltip to be activated by. What element do you want the tooltip to relate to?

Answer (score 0):

I was googling the same query "displaying tooltip dynamically" in VUE.  I got this as a result.

With further research I found that this syntax work:

`v-bind:title=data.res`

Here it is used in a forloop:

```html
<div v-for="item in data">
    <div v-bind:title=item.from >{{item.from}} | {{item.date}}</div> <----- HERE ---
</div>
```